# Hypothesis Testing / Undergrad stats

Tags: statistics

Let $y_1, y_2, . . .$ be independent observations that follow a Poisson distribution with mean λ. It is desired to test $H0:λ=λ_0 \,\textrm{vs}\, H1:λ=λ_0+λ_R$,where $λ_0$ and $λ_R$ are fixed and $\lambda_R > 0$ is a small reference improvement, in such a way that
P (accept H0|H1 true) = P (accept H1|H0 true) = $α$. By considering the parameterization $\theta = \log(\frac{λ}{λ_0})$, use a normal analogy to construct an approximate triangular test, ignoring overshoot.

This is the question I am answering and I have the solution. I am confused by how we work out that,

$\theta=\log(\frac{λ}{λ_0})⇒λ=λ_0e^θ\, \textrm{and}\, \logλ=\logλ_0 +\theta$.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You work those relation by properties of natural logarithm: $exp(log(x))=x$ and $log(\frac{x}{y})=log (x)-log (y)$.
First take exponential of both sides of $\theta =log\frac{\lambda}{\lambda_{0}}$ which leads to(after using the first property above):  $e^\theta =\frac{\lambda}{\lambda_{0}}.$ From here you can easily get $\lambda=e^\theta\lambda_{0}$.
Now,using the second property on the relation  $\theta =log\frac{\lambda}{\lambda_{0}}$ you obtain  $\theta =log(\lambda)-log(\lambda_{0})$ and from here you easily obtain the last relation $log(\lambda)=\theta +log(\lambda_{0})$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. I worded the question very badly to be honest. I am stuck on why we consider that paramaterisation. Do you have any clues as to why we choose this?

Comment: Right. Try to reformulate the question. I really don't understand what are you looking for. Sorry.

Comment: My question is just how does my lecturer [the question setter] know to use the parametisation $\theta = log(\frac{\lambda}{λ_0})$. It was terribly worded; so much so that it is unrecognisable.